# Lowering the degree of an polynomial with an assumption that the polynomial has a factor x^2+ax+b

Tags: replacement, polynomials

Let's assume $ x^{10}+x^5+1 $ has a factor $x^2+ax+b$

Then, If $x^2=-ax-b$,  $ x^{10}+x^5+1 =0$.

If we successively apply $x^2=-ax-b$ to $ x^{10}+x^5+1 $,

we can make $ x^{10}+x^5+1 $ to degree 1, such as $ mx +n $

and it should be that $m=0, n=0$

So having it on my mind, I tried,

```
x^10+x^5+1 //. x^2-> -a x -b
```

Didn't work.

```
x^10+x^5+1 //. x_^2-> -a x -b
```

Didn't work.

So, any suggestions? Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
x^10 + x^5 + 1 //. { x^c_?EvenQ :> (-a x - b)^(c/2), 
                     x^c_?OddQ  :> x (-a x - b)^((c - 1)/2)} // Expand
```

> ```
> 1 - b^5 + b^2 x - 5 a b^4 x + 2 a b x^2 - 10 a^2 b^3 x^2 + a^2 x^3 - 10 a^3 b^2 x^3 
> - 5 a^4 b x^4 - a^5 x^5
> ```

```
% // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

In order to get the first order polynomial in `x` at the end we can do this:

```
x^10 + x^5 + 1 //.{ x^c_?EvenQ :> Expand[(-a x - b)^(c/2)], 
                    x^c_?OddQ  :> Expand[x (-a x - b)^((c - 1)/2)]} // Collect[#, x] &
```

> ```
>    1 + a^3 b - a^8 b - 2 a b^2 + 7 a^6 b^2 - 15 a^4 b^3 + 10 a^2 b^4 - b^5 
> + (a^4 - a^9 - 3 a^2 b + 8 a^7 b + b^2 - 21 a^5 b^2 + 20 a^3 b^3 - 5 a b^4) x
> ```

**Edit**

This question deserves more detailed answer concerning solutions $a$ and $b$ to given system.

```
sol = 
  Solve[{ 1 + a^3 b - a^8 b - 2 a b^2 + 7 a^6 b^2 - 15 a^4 b^3 + 10 a^2 b^4 - b^5 == 0,
          a^4 - a^9 - 3 a^2 b + 8 a^7 b + b^2 - 21 a^5 b^2 + 20 a^3 b^3 - 5 a b^4 == 0}, 
         {a, b}] // FullSimplify;
```

There are `45` solutions:

```
Length @ sol
```

> ```
> 45
> ```

but to a given `b` there are multiple `a` :

```
Grid[ Prepend[{#[[1, 1, 2]], Sequence @@ #[[1, All, 2]]} & /@ 
      Transpose /@ Gather[ToRadicals @ sol, Last @ #1 == Last @ #2 &], 
              {"b", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a"}], Frame -> All] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure why polynomial division should be ruled out.  To "successively apply $x^2=−ax−b$ to $x^{10}+x^5+1$" is to me leads to the same steps as division.  Since the question was for any suggestions, I would suggest this:

```
Collect[
 PolynomialRemainder[x^10 + x^5 + 1, x^2 + a x + b, x],
 x]
(* 1 + a^3 b - a^8 b - 2 a b^2 + 7 a^6 b^2 - 15 a^4 b^3 + 10 a^2 b^4 - b^5 +
   (a^4 - a^9 - 3 a^2 b + 8 a^7 b + b^2 - 21 a^5 b^2 + 20 a^3 b^3 - 5 a b^4) x *)
```

Answer (score 3):

This way it can be achieved as well,

```
rulesk = {x^s_ /; s >= 2 /; Mod[s, 2] == 0 -> -(a x + b)^(s/2)}

rulesk2 = {x^s_ /; s >= 2 /; 
    Mod[s, 2] =!= 0 -> -x (a x + b)^((s - 1)/2)}
```

One rule will work on even power and one on odd power. Now using them as,

```
eq //. rulesk //. rulesk2 // Expand
```

$1 - b^5 - b^2 x - 5 a b^4 x - 2 a b x^2 - 10 a^2 b^3 x^2 - a^2 x^3 - 
 10 a^3 b^2 x^3 - 5 a^4 b x^4 - a^5 x^5$

or

```
eq //. rulesk2 //. rulesk // Expand
```

$1 - b^5 - b^2 x - 5 a b^4 x - 2 a b x^2 - 10 a^2 b^3 x^2 - a^2 x^3 - 
 10 a^3 b^2 x^3 - 5 a^4 b x^4 - a^5 x^5$

This is somewhat less worthy solution because it is always good to use build in functions like @Artes has used for even and odd power.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to make the replacements until only a first-degree polynomial is left. To do this, I'd modify Artes' answer (which I upvoted because I'm stealing from it) by using [`FixedPoint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FixedPoint.html):

```
firstDegree = 
 FixedPoint[
  Expand[# /. {x^c_?EvenQ :> (-a x - b)^(c/2), 
      x^c_?OddQ :> x (-a x - b)^((c - 1)/2)}] &, x^10 + x^5 + 1]

(*
==> 1 + a^3 b - a^8 b - 2 a b^2 + 7 a^6 b^2 - 15 a^4 b^3 + 
 10 a^2 b^4 - b^5 + a^4 x - a^9 x - 3 a^2 b x + 8 a^7 b x + b^2 x - 
 21 a^5 b^2 x + 20 a^3 b^3 x - 5 a b^4 x
*)

Simplify[
 First@Solve[Thread[CoefficientList[firstDegree, x] == 0], {a, b}]]

(* ==> {a -> 1, b -> 1} *)
```

This finds one of the solutions for `a` and `b` such that the assumption $m = n = 0$ is satisfied, as stated in your post.

Of course there are simpler methods (e.g., using `PolynomialQuotient`), but this is what you asked for.

Comment: Yes, I wanted make the replacements until only a first-degree polynomial is left. So this is the answer I wanted!

Comment: @KHKim It wasn't clear enough what you really wanted, so I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

`PolynomialReduce` is the function to use for this. Accept no substitutes (or substitutions).

--- edit ---

Actually `PolynomialRemainder is also fine here, and I see that (a) @Michael E2 had shown how to use that here and (b) I had upvoted that answer when it first appeared.

--- end edit ---

```
remainder = PolynomialReduce[x^10 + x^5 + 1, x^2 + a*x + b, x][[2]]

(* Out[32]= 1 + a^3 b - a^8 b - 2 a b^2 + 7 a^6 b^2 - 15 a^4 b^3 + 
 10 a^2 b^4 - b^5 + (a^4 - a^9 - 3 a^2 b + 8 a^7 b + b^2 - 
    21 a^5 b^2 + 20 a^3 b^3 - 5 a b^4) x *)
```

To get say rational solutions in the variables `{a,b]` one could then do as below.

```
Select[{a, b} /. Solve[CoefficientList[remainder, x] == 0], 
 Element[##, Rationals] &]

(* Out[38]= {{1, 1}} *)
```

In place of the `Solve` one might instead do `SolveAlways[remainder == 0, x]`.

Of course if one wants a factorization over the rationals, there is already `Factor` for that.