# help with simplifying function

Tags: simplifying-expressions, series-expansion

I am computing the 4th order talyor approximation of this function 
$$\big(\frac{b}{g-x}\big)^{0.25}$$

The analytic textbook result is:

$$b^{0.25} \big(\frac{1}{g^{0.25}}+\frac{0.25 x}{g^{1.25}}+\frac{0.15625x^2}{g^{2.25}}+\frac{0.117188 x^3}{g^{3.25}}+\frac{0.0952148 x^4}{g^{4.25}}\big)$$

When I do it in Mathematica:

```
nonLin = (b/(g - x))^0.25
taylorLin = Normal[Series[nonLin , {x, 0, 4}] // Simplify]
```

I get this:

$$x^4 \left(\frac{0.126465 b^4}{g^8 \left(\frac{b}{g}\right)^{3.75}}-\frac{0.03125 \left(\frac{b}{g}\right)^{0.25}}{g^4}\right)+\frac{0.117188 b^3 x^3}{g^6 \left(\frac{b}{g}\right)^{2.75}}+\frac{b x^2 \left(\frac{0.25
   g}{\left(\frac{b}{g}\right)^{0.75}}-\frac{0.09375 b}{\left(\frac{b}{g}\right)^{1.75}}\right)}{g^4}+\frac{0.25 x \left(\frac{b}{g}\right)^{0.25}}{g}+\left(\frac{b}{g}\right)^{0.25}$$

Is there a method to obtain the same nice representation as the analytic textbook solution ? ... to simplify it somehow?

EDIT:
If I use 1/4 in the exponent, the reuslt looks much nicer. However, it could still be simplified:

```
nonLin = (b/(g - x))^(1/4)
taylorLin = Normal[Series[nonLin , {x, 0, 4}] // Simplify]
```

$$\frac{195 x^4 \sqrt[4]{\frac{b}{g}}}{2048 g^4}+\frac{15 x^3 \sqrt[4]{\frac{b}{g}}}{128 g^3}+\frac{5 x^2 \sqrt[4]{\frac{b}{g}}}{32 g^2}+\frac{x \sqrt[4]{\frac{b}{g}}}{4 g}+\sqrt[4]{\frac{b}{g}}$$

Comment: Use `1/4` instead of `0.25` in the exponent.

Comment: The question is not clear: the solution you have shown is already analytic. Can you show, what are you after?

Comment: @J.M.issomewhatokay. Thanks a lot for your comment. Please have a look at my edit.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch I want the output to look like the analytic equation from the text book.( I edited my question)

Comment: Aha, then use please the advice of @J. M. is somewhat okay given above.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch Please see my edit. I used his advice, but the result is not identical.

Comment: @james you are expanding a different expression than the one you wrote

Comment: @Konstantinos Thanks ! Little typo. I fixed it.

Comment: @james Is it also possible that there is another typo? Is it b^(0.25)+parenthesis or times the parenthesis? The point is that you can calculate in a second the first Taylor term in pen and paper, and there is no apparent reason why b vanishes.

Comment: @Konstantinos Yes, you are right. Sorry for that! I fixed it.

Comment: @james "the result is not identical" to what? You should explain in a more precise way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
nonLin = (b/(g - x))^0.25;
taylorLin1 = 
  Simplify[Normal[Series[nonLin, {x, 0, 4}]], {b > 0, g > 0}];
taylorLin2 = b^0.25*Expand[taylorLin1/b^0.25]
```

The results looks as follows:

[image]

Done. Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

You can take a constant factor `(b/g)^.25` from the sum, then the sum is similar to what's in the book

```
Normal[Series[(1/(1 - x/g))^.25, {x, 0, 4}]]

Out[]= 1. + (0.25 x)/g + (0.15625 x^2)/g^2 + (0.117188 x^3)/g^3 + (
 0.0952148 x^4)/g^4
```

Answer (score 1):

This is using the reply found [Factorization](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/50432/tell-mathematica-to-factor-something-specific) here.

It is not giving the EXACT same result, but it is a matter of just looking the output and perform some minimal algebra in the end or just simplifying terms by hand in the end.

```
nonLin = (b/(g - x))^(1/4)
taylorLin = Series[nonLin, {x, 0, 4}]
sfactor[k_, p_, func_] := 
 HoldForm[StandardForm[k]]*StandardForm[func@(p*1/k)]
sfactor[(b)^(1/4), taylorLin, Apart] // Normal
```

Hopefully helpful.

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify) afterwards, you can provide an assumption to [`Series`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series):

```
Series[(b/(g - x))^0.25, {x, 0, 4}, Assumptions->b>0&&g>0] //TeXForm
```

> $b^{0.25`} \left(\frac{1}{g}\right)^{0.25`}+0.25` b^{0.25`} \left(\frac{1}{g}\right)^{1.25`} x+0.15625` b^{0.25`}
>    \left(\frac{1}{g}\right)^{2.25`} x^2+0.1171875` b^{0.25`} \left(\frac{1}{g}\right)^{3.25`} x^3+0.09521484375`
>    b^{0.25`} \left(\frac{1}{g}\right)^{4.25`} x^4+O\left(x^5\right)$