# Function to write an algebraic expression in terms of another

Tags: physics, algebraic-manipulation, algebra, factorization

So I'm working on a physics problem. I have two functions:

$\rho = \frac{F}{(\beta F^\alpha+1)^\frac{1}{\alpha}}$, $p = - \frac{F}{(\beta F^\alpha+1)^\frac{1}{\alpha}} + \frac{4}{3}\frac{F}{(\beta F^\alpha+1)^{1+\frac{1}{\alpha}}}$

Just by looking at $p$, I can tell it can be algebraically manipulated in order to write it, explicitly, in terms of $\rho$. Indeed:

$p= \frac{\rho}{3}(1-4\beta\rho^\alpha)$

Every math operation I do by hand on this project, I check it on Mathematica just to make sure I don't screw it up. Sometimes I use functions like Simplify or FullSimplify to make my life easier. For example, if I use Simplify[$\rho$], I get a nice reduced expression, and the same for Simplify[$p$]. Nevertheless, I'd love for my program to write $p$ in terms of $\rho$ so I don't have to do it manually as I did above. I'm assuming a way to do this is to tell Mathematica to factor the explicit form of $\rho$ out of $p$, but I'm not sure. Either way, I haven't been able to do this (the factorizing). So far, I've read about the function FactorTerms and even an specific one shown in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/50432/tell-mathematica-to-factor-something-specific), but none of this work as I want them to.

I'm assuming a function like this already exists or one may be defined simply, but I just can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a concrete example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi @Vicente, and welcome to MSE! In addition to what Bob suggested, could you please include Mathematica's code for your functions, so that people don't need to retype it?

Comment: **I can tell it can be algebraically manipulated** are you sure? I just checked,. Your desired $d$ does not match. When I do it by hand, this is what I get ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1ZU9.png) $$\rho  \left(\frac{4}{3} \left(\frac{\rho }{F}\right)^{\alpha }-1\right)$$

Comment: Copy-pasteable input? Without which this is not a viable question for this forum.

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
ρ = F/(β*F^α + 1)^(1/α)
d = -(F/(β*F^α + 1)^((1/α))) + 4/3 F/(β*F^α + 1)^(1 + 1/α)
d /. (1 + F^α β) :> (F/HoldForm[ρ])^α
PowerExpand[%] // Simplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Screen shot

[image: Mathematica graphics]

V 13.2

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

A more hands off approach, that still requires an guessed substitution, in this case

```
(β*F^α + 1) -> q
```

and then we eliminate `q`.

Also, I choose a somehow more verbose code to avoid lingering definitions and keep a [clean kernel](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/175670/10397).

Surprisingly, not all combinations of Reduce, Eliminate and Solve work as effectively.  These two options do work for this case:

### Eliminate `(β*F^α + 1)` by hand

```
Block[
    {
        q,
        subs = ( (β*F^α + 1) -> q ), (* Put your intuition here *)
        expre1 = ρ == F/(β*F^α + 1)^(1/α),
        expre2 = d == (F/(β*F^α + 1)^((1/α))) + 4/3 F/(β*F^α + 1)^(1 + 1/α)
    },
    Assuming[
        {F, β, α, ρ, q} ∈ PositiveReals,
        FullSimplify[
            expre2 /. subs /. Solve[expre1 /. subs, q]
        ]
    ]
]
```

[image]

### Eliminate `(β*F^α + 1)` using the third argument of `Solve`

Or also alternatively

```
Block[
    {
        q,
        subs = ( (β*F^α + 1) -> q ), (* Put your intuition here *)
        expre1 = ρ == F/(β*F^α + 1)^(1/α),
        expre2 = d ==(F/(β*F^α + 1)^((1/α))) + 4/3 F/(β*F^α + 1)^(1 + 1/α)
    },
    Assuming[
        {F, β, α, ρ, q} ∈ PositiveReals,
        Solve[
            Reduce[{expre2, expre1}/.subs]
            , {d}
            , {q} (* Undocumented "Eliminate" feature*)
            , InverseFunctions->True
        ]
    ]
]
Simplify@%
```

Comment: I'm asking further clarification about this undocumented way of evaluating `Solve` in [this other question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/279004/10397).