# Eliminate variable with partially documented Solve feature Solve[eqns,vars,elims]. Robust?

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation, undocumented

The [Eliminating Variables](https://reference.wolframcloud.com/cloudplatform/tutorial/ManipulatingEquationsAndInequalities.html#1009) section on [Manipulating Equations and Inequalities](https://reference.wolframcloud.com/cloudplatform/tutorial/ManipulatingEquationsAndInequalities.html) documentation quotes an otherwise undocumented feature for [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html)

> `Solve[eqns,vars,elims]`  find solutions for `vars`, eliminating the
> variables `elims`

[image]

However, that structure is not mentioned in the documentation for [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) itself, where the third argument is the *Domain* and not the variables to be eliminated.

[image]

This works

```
Solve[{x + y == 6 a + 3 b, y == 9 a + 2 x}, {x}, {a}]
(* {{x -> 1/7 (9 b - y)}}  *)
```

Equivalent to

```
Solve[Eliminate[{x + y == 6 a + 3 b, y == 9 a + 2 x}, a], {x}]
```

And different from

```
Solve[{x + y == 6 a + 3 b, y == 9 a + 2 x}, {x,y}]
(* {{x->-a+b,y->7 a+2 b}} *)
```

On [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/279000/10397) I found a form that works, but almost any variation of it, doesn't. Either it takes forever to evaluate, or it doesn't evaluate.

This works,

```
Block[
    {
        q,
        subs = ( (β*F^α + 1) -> q ), (* Put your intuition here *)
        expre1 = ρ == F/(β*F^α + 1)^(1/α),
        expre2 = d ==(F/(β*F^α + 1)^((1/α))) + 4/3 F/(β*F^α + 1)^(1 + 1/α)
    },
    Assuming[
        {F, β, α, ρ, q} ∈ PositiveReals,
        Solve[
            Reduce[{expre2, expre1}/.subs]
            , {d}
            , {q} (* Undocumented "Eliminate" feature*)
            , InverseFunctions->True
        ]
    ]
]
Simplify@%
```

It does give the expected solution despite the warning: "This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve."

[image]

This version `Solve` doesn't evaluate.

```
Assuming[
    {F, β, α, ρ, q} ∈ PositiveReals,
    Block[
        {
            q,
            subs = ( (β*F^α + 1)->q ),
            expre1 = ρ == F/(β*F^α + 1)^(1/α),
            expre2 = d == (F/(β*F^α + 1)^((1/α))) + 4/3 F/(β*F^α + 1)^(1 + 1/α)
        },
        Simplify@Solve[Reduce[ {expre2, expre1}/.subs], {d}, {q}, InverseFunctions->True]
    ]
]
```

Which makes me believe probably that feature is not as robust as the alternatives.

There is [an answer by @Mr.Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/41263/10397) that acknowledges the existence of this feature in `Solve` and [`Reduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html), and points out that this feature used to be [documented in older versions](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v7/ref/Solve.html), but it doesn't answer any of the following questions:

꘏ **Why is the feature not documented in new versions?**

꘏ **What is the way to eliminate the ambiguity between *Domain* and *variables to be eliminated* as the third argument?**

꘏ **Why does *Mathematica* warns that `Solve` can't solve but gives the solution anyways?**

꘏ **Does `Solve[eqns,vars,elims]` have more limited scope or utility than combining  `Solve[Eliminate[eqns, elims], vars]` ?**

Comment: Ok, the ambiguity seems to removed by the brackets `{}`? It looks like if the arguments is  in brackets the argument is interpreted as variables to be eliminated, if not it is interpreted as a domain. Can somebody confirm?

Comment: `Solve[x == y, z, w]` yields `Solve::bdomv`, which supports the theory that `elims` should be a list. (That's been my assumption for years, ever since `elims` disappeared from the doc pages for `Solve` and `Reduce` -- Note `Solve[eqns, vars, elims, dom]` is possible, too.